# How do I select values from an enum in Kotlin and Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, swiftui, android-jetpack-compose, picker, segmentedcontrol

I'm in the process of converting my iOS app to Android. I have several enums that are used to filter an array. I have Categories (Womens, Mens, Mixed), Leagues and Divisions.

In SwiftUI, I am using a `Picker {}.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())`. I'm looking for a way to do the same in Jetpack Compose. The keywords I've searched for haven't turned up anything.

So, how do I visually select values from a Kotlin enum in Jetpack Compose?

[image: Categories and Divisions Picker]

Comment: Like this? https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#ExposedDropdownMenuBox(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function1) You'll need to reference String resources in your enum (give the enum class a `val resourceId: Int` property) to use for the Text component in the for loop where you add the DropDownMenuItem entries.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a complete list of Material Components. It seems what I want is [Segmented Buttons](https://m3.material.io/components/segmented-buttons/overview) - except it's status is "Planned".

I also found Tabs in Material Design. They might do the trick, too.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it might help you build one. It doesn't seem hard to build, so I don't know why Google is dragging their heels creating basic widgets. https://gist.github.com/zach-klippenstein/7ae8874db304f957d6bb91263e292117

Comment: "Segmented Buttons" are still not available for Compose as of May 22, 2023. If you're comfortable with importing such a component into compose, the toggle / segmented buttons are available in the classic xml-based design system (and it seems like they have been available for over 3 years). https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Button.md#toggle-button

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Jetpack Compose "equivalent":

```
@Composable fun MyExposedDropdownMenuBox() {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val categories = arrayOf("Women", "Men", "Mixed")
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedText by remember { mutableStateOf(categories[0]) }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(32.dp)) {
        ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
            expanded = expanded,
            onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded }
        ) {
            TextField(
                value = selectedText,
                onValueChange = {},
                readOnly = true,
                trailingIcon = { 
                    ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(
                        expanded = expanded
                    )
                },
                modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor()
            )    
            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
            ) {
                categories.forEach { item ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(text = item) },
                        onClick = {
                            selectedText = item
                            expanded = false
                            Toast.makeText(context, 
                                           item, 
                                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll have a look at this later today, but I really don't want a drop down menu. I want all the options displayed on screen. I don't want the user to touch/click 2-3 times to accomplish such a simple task.